# ANDROID JAVA JAR file executed on server?

Tags: android, jar

I have a jar file that I need run after 3 other strings are gathered within a promgram/app. I was wondering if I could create a server / install java on it  through ssh/http (whatever) to the server from within the app and use e.g python  to execute the jar (with the 3 strings)

```
java -jar myfile.jar,$1,$2,$3
```

Then return the output to the android app to complete the operation?

The jar file basically is used as a key which opens a socket to start a stream file which is run by other process (webserver or socket is `8080`)... so my thought is to have a reverse connection: port `8080` listening on android box, port `22` (ssh Proof of Concept) android to server which opens socket and sends info back to android box via port 8080.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, you can do it that, but question is too broad and opinion-based to be answered here. But server on Android device... that's not a good idea, specially if GSM network is on the way. I think you don't need anything that complicated to simply remotely run a JAR file.

Comment: its a media center addon...works on any system that has java installed...was able to install java as its own addon within media center on some devices that java wasnt or couldnt be installed....however android has no java base and will not except executable files ie..(JAVA) to run the addon...the only way i can think of is getting the python script that calls the jar to try and use a jre on a server and send the results back...however the results send the key for the socket opened on the android box...any suggestions would be helpful.